# How to save Firestore query in firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I build the front screen of an eCommerce app and there are cards in the front screen. Right now I am saving two properties in the firestore(backend) as List[tag,subTag] so, when there is click in the card then it goes to next screen and makes FutureBuilder with:

> future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
> .where('tag', isEqualTo: _selectedBrand)
> .where('subTag', isEqualTo: _selectedTag)

so it is limiting me.

What do I want ?

I want dynamic query to be saved in firestore so that if I want let's say to display products where discount is greater than 40% I could show that or if I want to fetch product which is of particular brand so how could I do that from admin app.
(if any idea how company like amazon or flipkart make there front screen so dynamic I am fresher and using flutter).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If any of the answers below have solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark or just [upvote it if it was useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a field discount of type numbers in firestore and get QuerySnapshot based on that

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new field in your document within the firestore so you can do those "dynamic" queries.

When you use the where function, it returns a Query type, which you can use to keep adding filters to... if you try to obtain the result from the ref, your filters will be ignored.
Instead, save the query in a variable and retrieve the results from there.

You can also use [compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#dart_11)